# How can we prebuilt 3rd app to android ROM

Tags: android, facebook, makefile, rom, android-rom

I'm try to prebuilt **Facebook** to my ROM in two way
*Android.mk* file like below. But Facebook till does not work ...

## 1. try this way

```
my_archs:=arm arm64

my_src_arch :=$(call get-prebuilt-src-arch,$(my_archs))

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS :=@lib/armeabi-v7a/*.so

LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH :=arm
```

- Not any .so lib under */system/lib/* or *system/3rdapp/Facebook/lib/*

  Log show us that
  *dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.facebook.katana/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit*

## 2. try this(extra the so lib from apk file )

```
my_archs:=arm arm64

my_src_arch :=$(call get-prebuilt-src-arch,$(my_archs))

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS :=lib/armeabi-v7a/1.so lib/armeabi-v7a/2.so

LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH :=arm
```

- so lib will be copy to */system/3rdapp/Facebook/lib* success,However,PMS parser failed cause by `NativeLibraryHelper`

  > I NativeLibraryHelper: Couldn't open temporary file name: /system/3rdapp/Facebook/lib/arm/tmp.regBEn: Read-only file system
  >   W PackageManager: Failed to scan /system/3rdapp/Facebook: Error unpackaging native libs for app, errorCode=-18

error code define in PackageManager.java

`/**
     * Installation return code: this is passed to the
     * {@link IPackageInstallObserver} if a secure container mount point
     * couldn't be accessed on external media.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    @SystemApi
    public static final int INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR = -18;`

I have dump `dumpsys package com.facebook.kanta`,show `Instruction Set: arm64`

## Question

1、How can I prebuild Facebook to my rom?such Facebook..

2、Why does Facebook running arm64?(LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH does not be used?)

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: @wossoneri Yeah. I have solved this issue

Comment: i'm facing a issue about embed 3rd party APK in my rom. could you leave your email ? i have some questions to ask. @caopeng